# how to configure spring 3.2.3 to work with javassist?

Tags: java, spring, proxy, javassist

It seems that Spring 3.2.3 still using CGLIB proxy.

```
ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$5dac1486$$FastClassByCGLIB$$a9435bbd
```

how to configure spring 3.2.3 to work with [javassist](http://www.csg.ci.i.u-tokyo.ac.jp/~chiba/javassist/)?

Comment: Not it will only work with cglib to javassist.

Comment: you mean it cant work with javassist?

Comment: Correct. Spring uses CGLIB (always for configuration classes) or JDK Dynamic Proxies. Those are the only to proxy solutions working with Spring. Javassist isn't one of them.